# how to play audio mp3 in ionic when page ( view) is loaded

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

i want to play audio mp3 in background when my page is loaded, so if i use button click, it works but if i try  to play it when   my controller is loaded with $state , it doesn't work :

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
.controller("ExampleController", function($scope, $cordovaMedia) {

    $scope.play = function(url) {
        var my_media = new Media(url,
            function () {
                console.log("playAudio() : success");
           },
            function (err) {
                 console.log("playAudio() : : "+err);
           });
        my_media.play();
    };
   $scope.play('/android_asset/www/someAudio.mp3');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for your help, the answer is :

```
  $scope.play = function() {
      var mp3URL = getMediaURL("sounds/yourMp3AudioFile.mp3");
      var media = new Media(mp3URL, null, null, mediaStatusCallback);
      media.play();
   } 
   var mediaStatusCallback = function(status) {
       if(status == 1) {
           $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Loading...'});
       } else {
           $ionicLoading.hide();
       }
   }
   function getMediaURL(s) {
       var isAndroid = ionic.Platform.isAndroid();
       if(isAndroid) return "/android_asset/www/" + s;
       return s;
    }
   $timeout(function() {
       $scope.play();
   }, 1000);
```

Comment: Hi. I tried the same code but it is not working. It always shows the Loading... popup and it never goes away. Where do I put the mp3 file in my Ionic project? As of now, I am trying hard with a file on the internet. please help.

Answer (score 1):

$scope.play is not defined. Did you mean to define a function where my_media is instead? You would need to change it a bit:

```
$scope.play = function(url) {
    var my_media = new Media(url,
        function () {
            console.log("playAudio() : success");
       },
        function (err) {
             console.log("playAudio() : : "+err);
       });
    my_media.play();
};
```

Comment: No, not really. You aren't defining play in the $scope object. You defined play as a function in the global scope. You want, I believe:  $scope.play = function(etc)  and then $scope.play('someurl');

Comment: yes, sorry ! i've edite it again ... but it doesn't work

Comment: Ok, so what error do you get? Also, are you waiting for the deviceReady event?

Comment: This page is not the home page , so the Divice is ready and I  didn't get any error ... when I call the function with a button it works fine but when I make the call as I describe it, it does not work .

Comment: Can you update the code to show how you run it from a button?

Comment: it's a simple ng-click  like that : <button ng-click="play()"> play</button>

Comment: As far as I know, what you have should work when the page loads the controller. I'd check remote debugging and your console. Ensure you don't have an error there.